# What factors should be considered when choosing one agent over another?

Tags: fifa-18

I am playing Fifa 18's story mode, and I'm at the level where I have to choose whether to leave the Agent Micheal or keep him.

What is the better choice? What are the changes or differences between leaving or keeping him? Do I get more matches or a different ending to the story?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without spoiling too much: Nothing happens to *your* career directly.

After keeping or firing Michael the phone will still ring and dad wants to setup a new opportunity for you, which is the same in both cases. The difference will be that either Michael is with you cooperating with dad or dad will be your manager when you chose to fire Michael.